# Get time for a specific geolocation

Tags: iphone, ios, sdk, geolocation, timezone

I have the lat and long of a location and want to know whether it is day or night in that location or at least know the time there.

Is there a way to do this without using web services?

Comment: for the user's current location or an arbitrary location?

Comment: Do you really want to know just whether the sun is up? Because that's a single computation for the whole earth. But the local time is much harder, that changes with politics!

Comment: @emrys57 is absolutly correct, calculating the tz is a nightmare compared to simple sunset sunrise for location defined by latitude (an dlongitude). You should rename your question

Comment: If you want to actually resolve the correct time zone, rather than just sunrise/sunset, please see [this community wiki entry](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16086962/634824)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an explanation of how to calculate the time of sunrise and sunset at http://williams.best.vwh.net/sunrise_sunset_algorithm.htm

That produces a result in UTC. The phone knows the current time in UTC. So you can then work out whether the sun has set, and how long ago, at the location you want.